# Window key+arrows periodically stop working

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys, windows-key

I use the Windows key+arrows to arrange my windows on my 3 monitors quite often.  However, every so often, they simply stop working.  The only way I have found to get them working again is to reboot the system.

Has anyone encountered this problem and know how to get them working without a reboot?  I've seen other questions about them not working, but they all seem to be permanently not working and the solution is changing configurations.  However, mine always work fine after a clean boot.

Ideas?

Comment: During this time, does pressing the `Win` key once bring up the start menu? Have you tried with another keyboard? If your keyboard has multiple `Win` keys, does this problem persists when trying either key?

Comment: Pressing the key once correctly brings up the start menu.  Other combinations, such as win+E, Win+R, Win+D, etc., all seem to work fine.  My keyboard only has one 'win' key.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem with another keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that the Clean boot can work fine without any issue? If so, it can be caused by 3rd part conflict.

You can determine which one can be the cause by using dichotomy in MSconfig. Checking on half of Non-Microsoft service and restart, determining which half of the services cause the issue and repeating to check half of the problematic half services.

Details about troubleshooting by using Clean boot, refer to this link:

How to perform a clean boot

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135

Comment: I've done a clean boot, and it works fine after boot.  It simply periodically stops.  Although it hasn't done so since I posted the question.  I believe that you are probably right in that it is probably some 3rd party app that is conflicting with the keycodes.  I am now keeping a close watch to see if I can tell if/when it stops working in an attempt to identify what app is conflicting.  I will update my question if I am able to identify the culprit.  Thanks for the suggestion.